# Need help with message declaration

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I wish to use a message type that i created in one of my packages in my other package, but for some reason it doesn't work :

The package were the message is declared named ***dany_controller_pkg*** and the message type is ***velocity_derection***.

In order to use this message type in my other new package, i add to the new package Manifest file, the following dependency :

```
<depend package="dany_controller_pkg"/>
```

and included in the cpp file of my new package the following declaration :

```
#include <dany_controller_pkg/velocity_derection.h>
```

Still for some reason when i compile, the compiler doesn't recognize the imported message type.

The exact compiler error is:

```
Unresolved inclusion: <dany_controller_pkg/velocity_derection.h>
```

(Also, in the original package this message type works fine)

What am i missing ?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56002/need-help-with-message-declaration/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 192 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-22**:
Post the compiler error, please.

**Comment by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on 2013-02-22**:
I added the exact compiler error, you can see it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turned out that the problem is with the eclipse !

For some reason when i compile using Eclipse it marks all the places where i using **velocity_derection** topic as errors, and writes that they are Unresolved. But still the compilation succeeds and the program works fine. I have no idea why it behave in this way.

Nevertheless, I want to thank you KruseT and TommyP for your great help !

Also, if someone have any suggestions why it happens, I be happy to know.

---

Originally posted by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) with karma: 192 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1